# Formatting text output from DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, text, datagridview

I'm writing the values of two (1 column) DGVs and a text box to a text file.  The text box value is the heading, DGV1 is a column of strings (such as SI CA S C...etc) and DGV2 is a column of numbers of the format 11.23 or 0.01.  The formats are exactly how I want them as displayed in the DGVs, but that formatting doesn't carry over to the text file these values are output to.  Here's what I want the textfile to look like:

```
A012345 101 1.03
SI 32.13
C   1.45
CA  0.03
```

Here's what I'm getting instead:

```
A012345 101 1.03
SI32.13015
C1.452359
CA0.032568
```

Here's the code:

```
 Try
        Dim da, da2 As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ds, ds2 As DataSet

        'open connection to nit2.xlsm'
        Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & TextBox2.Text & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""")

        'Fill dataviewgrid1 with element symbols, string, once'
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$A:A" & lastrow & "]", cn)
        ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


        '''''''''''''loop through each sample and write to text file'''''''''''''''''''''''
        da2 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$B:B" & lastrow & "]", cn)
        ds2 = New System.Data.DataSet
        da2.Fill(ds2)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)

        'write sample heading to textbox1, looped'
        TextBox1.Text = "Q0" & xlWsheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value & " " & xlWsheet2.Cells(1, 2).Value


        'write to text file each data analysis point with formatted heading, looped'
        Dim title As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim sub_title As String = title.Substring(0, 16)

        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fName, True)
            writer.WriteLine(sub_title) 'heading'

            Dim symbol, SymbolT As String
            Dim compo As String
            For cell1 As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
                symbol = Me.DataGridView1(0, cell1).Value 'element symbol'
                symbolT = symbol.Trim
                compo = Me.DataGridView2(0, cell1).Value 'composition'
                writer.WriteLine(symbolT & compo)
            Next

            writer.Close()
        End Using

        cn.Close()
```

How can I format the numbers from DGV2 so that they only display to 2 decimals?

I also need to set the spacing between SI and 32.13 (for example) so that the decimal points in each line line up.

Formatting...anyone?

Comment: By the way, don't you miss one row with `For cell1 As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)` - seem the last row is somewhat left (unless that row is empty, which makes sense)

Comment: Yes, thanks for that fsintegral.  I guess that was left over from an earlier version.  Good eye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
Dim symbol As String
Dim compo As String
Dim symbolSpan As Integer = 0 ' stores the MaxLength of symbol
Dim compoSpan As Integer = 0 ' stores the Max Integer Part Length of compo
Dim symbolList As New List(Of String) ' all trimmed symbol
Dim compoList As New List(Of String) ' all trimmed compo
Dim compoIntLengthList As New List(Of Integer)
Dim doubleValue As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
    ' element symbol...
    symbol = Me.DataGridView1(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim()
    symbolList.Add(symbol)
    If symbol.Length > symbolSpan Then
        symbolSpan = symbol.Length
    End If

    ' composition...
    If Double.TryParse(Me.DataGridView2(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim(), doubleValue) Then
        compoList.Add(doubleValue.ToString("R"))
        ' well, the ToString("R") is not really the displayed value.
        ' if your DGV allows scientific display for Double then 
        ' you'll have to handle that here with another code...
        compo = doubleValue.ToString("F0") ' gets the Integer part length...
        compoIntLengthList.add(compo.Length)
        If compo.Length > compoSpan Then
            compoSpan = compo.Length
        End If
    Else
        ' ohhhh ! the Cell doesn't contain a valid number... :/ 
        compo = Me.DataGridView2(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim()
        compoList.Add(compo)
        If compo.Contains(".") Then ' Watch out culture about dots and commas...
            If compoSpan < compo.IndexOf("."c) Then
                compoSpan = compo.IndexOf("."c)
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.IndexOf("."c))
        Else
            If compoSpan < compo.Length Then
                compoSpan = compo.Length
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.Length)
        End If
    End If
Next

symbolSpan = symbolSpan + 1 ' space between symbol and compo.

Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fName, True)
    writer.WriteLine(sub_title) 'heading'

    For i = 0 To symbolList.Count - 1
        symbol = symbolList.Item(i)
        While symbol.Length < symbolSpan
            symbol = symbol + " "
        End While

        compo = compoList.Item(i)
        j = compoIntLengthList.Item(i)
        While j < compoSpan
            compo = " " + compo
            j = j + 1 ' this is what was causing the endless loop.
        End While

        writer.WriteLine(symbol & compo)
    Next
    symbolList.Clear()
    symbolList= Nothing
    compoList.Clear()
    compoList = Nothing
    compoIntLengthList.Clear()
    compoIntLengthList = Nothing

    writer.Close()
End Using
```

I haven't tested the code. **Just written it on the fly..** The approach looks ugly (and I agree) but that's one way I remember so far. Could be better with `String.Format` or `StringBuilder` I guess but don't remember well how those ones works, sorry.

---

### EDIT : Missed the two decimals part...

Oh, sorry ! You want only two decimals.. Replace this :

```
        compoList.Add(doubleValue.ToString("R"))
```

by this :

```
        compoList.Add(doubleValue.ToString("F2"))
        ' or this :
        compoList.Add(doubleValue.ToString("#.##")) ' to allow 0 or 1 decimal aswell
```

and replace this part :

```
        ' ohhhh ! the Cell doesn't contain a valid number... :/ 
        compo = Me.DataGridView2(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim()
        compoList.Add(compo)
        If compo.Contains(".") Then ' Watch out culture about dots and commas...
            If compoSpan < compo.IndexOf("."c) Then
                compoSpan = compo.IndexOf("."c)
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.IndexOf("."c))
        Else
            If compoSpan < compo.Length Then
                compoSpan = compo.Length
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.Length)
        End If
```

by this :

```
        ' ohhhh ! the Cell doesn't contain a valid number... :/ 
        compo = Me.DataGridView2(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim()
        If compo.Contains(".") Then ' Watch out culture about dots and commas...
            If compoSpan < compo.IndexOf("."c) Then
                compoSpan = compo.IndexOf("."c)
            End If
            If compo.Length > (compo.IndexOf("."c) + 3) Then
                compo = compo.SubString(0, compo.IndexOf("."c) + 3)
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.IndexOf("."c))
        Else
            If compoSpan < compo.Length Then
                compoSpan = compo.Length
            End If
            compoIntLengthList.add(compo.Length)
        End If
        compoList.Add(compo)
```

Comment: I added some bits about the two decimals thing (missed that)

Comment: I'm getting a null reference exception error when I run: Object reference not set to instance of an object.  It pops up towards the beginning on the line that says-

    symbol = Me.DataGridView1(0, i).Value.ToString().Trim

Comment: Hmmm, DGV reference is set up OK... I'm thinking the ToString method is trying to convert a null value to a string?  The heading for DGV1 is "SAMPLE", but it shouldn't be reading that.  The first row is "SI", which shouldn't be a problem.  For sure, I don't have any empty cells...

Comment: What is the value of "i" in the debugger when the exception occurs ? It should highlight the offending row..

Comment: @BG- : DataGridView behaviour : If you allow user to add a row (Property `AllowUserToAddRows`) and the DGV has `RowHeadersVisible` Property set to `True`, then it **automatically adds an empty Row** at the end of the table. That's why I said _"... (unless that row is empty, which makes sense)"_ in the other comment. With that empty Row, `For cell1 As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)` is correct : discard the last (empty) Row (it depends on the DGV Properties and/or if those could be changed at runtime)

Comment: @fsintegral-: I'm not getting the null reference error anymore (and all I did was turn off the computer for the night!).  RowHeadersVisible = False, btw.

Now I've got other issues- :(
I'm not getting any errors during debugging, but a couple of odd things are happening.  TextBox1 is not being populated like it was earlier, a blank data1.txt is being generated, and finally, none of the controls on the console window are clickable AFTER I run the above program.

Comment: Your question was about _Formatting text output from DataGridView in vb.net_, not about populating the TextBox1 or loading the Tables. The code I wrote starts **after** your `Dim sub_title As String = title.Substring(0, 16)`. The part before that line is still required for your code  to work, but because that part has nothing to do with formatting, I didn't added it. Check for missing block starting from the line I mentionned to the up. Non clickable window is an **endless loop** (or a very long one) make evaluations of loops in your code by using the pause/step into debug modes.

Comment: Found the endless loop : forgot to increment j in the while block !

Comment: @BG- Corrected the While block causing the endless loop by adding a `j = j + 1` fix.

Comment: @fsintegral- Yep, I pasted right over those two DIM statements.  Thanks SO MUCH for this!  This gets me within arm's length of my goal.  You made my month! :)